# Unable to start/boot into custom kernel in FreeBSD

Tags: reboot, kernel, freebsd

I am trying to create a custom kernel in FreeBSD. After doing the buildkernel and installkernel when I reboot the system, it gets a panic and enters debugging(ddb4) mode instead of loading the new kernel. I am using FreeBSD on VMware and my native operating system is Widnows 10. Here is a few lines from the rebooted system.

```
enter fork_exit() at fork_exit+0x84/frame Bxfffffe001a1fdaf0 

enter fork_trampoline() at fork_trampoline+8xe/frame axfffffe001a1fdafE

--- trap , rip = 0, rsp = 0, rbp = 0 --- KDB: enter: panic 
[ thread pid 1 tid 100002 ] Stopped at db)

kdb_enter+0x3b:

db>
```

Comment: You, probably, didn't include some mandatory option in the kernel config file.

Comment: check https://fabrik.red/ probably could give you an idea about how to build the custom kernel: https://github.com/fabrik-red/images/blob/master/fabrik.kernel

Comment: The custom kernel configuration is ditto the original one, no options added or removed. It still isn't working.

Comment: updating your question with the full steps you are doing and outputs could help

Comment: You should, instead, ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or the FreeBSD mailing list or forum.